# DateTime.ParseExact strings to datetime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm about to begin cursing at my computer!

I have one program that output a datetime as a string, but I want to feed it into another as a datetime.

The string I get is on the form:

```
dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss
```

And I would like to find an appropriate way to get a DateTime object back.

I'm thinking something like:

```
string date = "11/07/14 18:19:20";

string dateformat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss";
DateTime converted_date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, 
         dateformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But several of the conversion of dates result in an Exception being thrown back with the message "Not valid timedate".

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `Parse` instead of `ParseExact`? I don't see anything wrong with what you have, but `Parse` should at least give you a result.

Comment: Ah right - the c# bit? Hmm... It been a while since I last read the FAQ, since it was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hour is not in 12-hour format. For 24-hour format, it's H.

```
            string date = "11/07/14 18:19:20";

        string dateformat = "dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss";
        DateTime converted_date = DateTime.ParseExact(date,
                 dateformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Wow! That did the trick! :-)

Website does not allow me to accept - yet. But it did work! :-)

Answer (score 3):

'hh' for hour is actually 12 hour clock, 01-12. I think you want 'HH' or 'H' for 24-hour clock ('HH' is zero-padded, 'H' is not). Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx for specific formats.